# SharePoint Search Results are visible to assigned Search Service Application user only

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, search-results, sharepoint-search, searchserviceapplication

I have SharePoint 2010 standalone installation on Windows 7.

I created a Search Center in a Site Collection. I created Search Service Application and provided a user(sp_search) to Crawling. It shows results to only sp_search user but not even me who is and administrator of the site. Crawling is also working fine.

I am not able to understand what is the reason for this.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error you are getting? also check if you grant them proper permission. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582314(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks Waqas. But actually permissions were fine because I was trying to search through farm administrator/ site collection administrator account. Anyways, I found my mistake though I tried to follow the procedure was given on internet in various articles. While creating Search Service Application, I was also creating a separate Application pool for it. But when i selected "SHAREPOINT - Web Services Default" application pool, it started showing result to administrator and other users as well. Can you please tell how application pool could be the reason for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I just changed the Application pool in Search Service Application I created. Earlier, I was creating a new Application Pool as "Search Admin Web Service" and "Search Query Web Service" but I am not able to understand how this Application pool could be an issue because in lot of articles and videos it is clearly told to create separate application pool. Can anybody help me to understand it please?

Thanks in advance.